# Spring Security SAML Examples

Tags: grails, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

I'm trying to configure several Spring and Grails applications to use Spring Security SAML, but I can't find good tutorial.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether it's 100% applicable to you. Here is Sprijng Oath and SAML integration tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/598581/How-to-integrate-Spring-oAuth-with-Spring-SAML

Also, take a look at this:
http://reddymails.blogspot.com/2013/06/integrating-jsf-web-applicataion-with.html